# Visual C# printing

Tags: c#, printing

I have a panel which contains pictures, textboxes and labels. I am trying to print this panel, which it successfully does with the following code:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (myPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom",
                                                              panel1.Width + 110,
                                                              panel1.Height + 110);
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest,
                                     int nYDest, int nWidth,
                                     int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc,
                                     int nXSrc, int nYSrc,
                                     int dwRop);

private void CaptureScreen(Panel pnl)
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = pnl.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = pnl.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }
private void PrintPage(System.Object sender,
                           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen(panel1);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 5, 5);
    }


    public Bitmap memoryImage { get; set; }
```

The printing quality is not great at all and you can't even read the text.
I'm trying to print the label on an A4 , so I put it's size 595 x 842 pixels. When it prints out I get it on 3/4 of the page instead of all of it. I think the problem might be the size because if I compare the page with the label on the screen, it's exactly the same... 
What can I do to print this well without increasing the size of the panel?

Comment: Golly why are you using `BitBlt`?

Comment: So...Should I remove it? If not, what should I replace it with? I'm a newbie and this isn't my code entirely...

Comment: The resolution of a printer is drastically higher than the resolution of your monitor.  So every single pixel on your panel is turned into a 6x6 blob of ink on the printer.  Sure, that doesn't look good, particularly so for text since the anti-aliasing pixels that make it look decent on the screen turn into boulders.  The mistake you made was thinking that this could work, it just doesn't.

Comment: What can be done then? If this doesn't work is there another way? The program I'm making is based on printing so I can't really discard this...

Comment: You need to code a __dedicated printPage__ event; make sure you set the `dpi` to a decent value and write the print code just as you would (or do) write it in the paint events for the screen..